# Replace some Rows of a Variable in Tensorflow With Boolean Mask and Index List

Tags: tensorflow, k-means

I am implementing a k-means on the sphere, starting out from @dga's [gist](https://gist.github.com/dave-andersen/265e68a5e879b5540ebc).
The unit-norm constraint basically means using inner products instead of pairwise distances, using `argmax` instead of `argmin` and sum+normalization instead of averaging to update the centroids.

Now I am trying to replace dead centroids with the least well represented data points.
`unsorted_segment_sum` will return a sum of 0 for dead centroids:

```
total = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(points, best_centroids, K)
```

From this I get a boolean mask of dead centroids:

```
deads = tf.equal(total, 0)
```

... a count of dead centroids:

```
 dead_count = tf.reduce_sum(tf.as_type(deads, 'int64'))
```

... and finally a list with the indices of the data points that are represented the worst by the current model:

```
_, dead_replacement_idx = tf.nn.top_k(-assignment_qualities, 
                                      k=dead_count, sorted=False)
```

Now how do I replace the dead centroids?
In numpy this would now come down to about this:

```
means[deads] = points[dead_replacement_idx]
```

How can I do something similar in Tensorflow?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206 ... I think someone is starting to work on that

Answer (score 0):

If you store your means in `Variables` you can use `scatter_update`

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()

means = tf.Variable(np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]), dtype=np.float32)
indices = tf.constant([0, 2])
new_mean = tf.constant([-1, -1], dtype=np.float32)

new_mean_matrix = tf.reshape(new_mean, [1, -1])
tile_shape = tf.pack([tf.size(indices), 1])
new_mean_matrix_tiled = tf.tile(new_mean_matrix, tile_shape) 
update_op = tf.scatter_update(means, indices, new_mean_matrix_tiled)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print "Before update"
print sess.run(means)
print "Updating rows", indices.eval(), "to", new_mean.eval()
sess.run(update_op)
print "After update"
print sess.run(means)
```

result

```
Before update
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.]]
Updating rows [0 2] to [-1. -1.]
After update
[[-1. -1.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [-1. -1.]]
```

Comment: In my case, `means` is a tensor *derived from* the `centroids` variable. If the assignments change, `centroids` and `cluster_assignments` are `assign()`ed inside a `with control_dependencies(): ... tf.group()`. I guess I could then do the `scatter_update()` afterwards, but I'd need another `control_dependencies()` to make sure the dead centroids are replaced *after* the `assign`?

Comment: the simplest way to ensure one set of calculations happens after the others is to use two different run calls. IE, `sess.run(update_variables); sess.run(do_calculation)`. If you use `with_dependencies`, make sure all the relevant ops are created inside `with_dependencies` block.